Problema al realizar filtrados en una pagina
Tengo una tienda WooCommerce en la cual se permite a los usuarios filtrar los productos, tanto por color, marca, etc.
Pero tengo un problema:
Por ejemplo: estoy posicionado en la pagina 3 de los productos, y decido aplicar un filtrado por color "rojo" (del cual solo hay 3 productos). En lugar de redirigirme a la pagina 1 que es donde se ven los resultados, me dice que la pagina no existe. (Eso debido a que obviamente no hay pagina 3 de resultados).
Les explico con urls mejor:
https://mystore.com/shop/page/2/ => URL desde la que aplique el filtro de color "rojo"
https://mystore.com/shop/?filter_color=rojo => URL a la que deberia redireccionar ya que NO hay page 2 porque solo hay 3 resultados.
https://mystore.com/shop/page/2/?filter_color=rojo => URL a la que me lleva y dice que no existe la pagina.
Alguien sabe como arreglar esto, o como se configura?
Les agreadezco de antemano su ayuda gente!

Verifica el link del color, el link debe tener (y mostrar) algo como: shop/?filter_color=rojo Pueda que el problema lo tengas en esas url

Si si es asi como esta, shop/filter_color=rojo
Si realizo el filtrado desde la pagina 1 no tengo ningun problema., el problema es cuando aplico el filtrado en la pagina 2 y los resultados del filtrado no alcanzan para una pagina 2

Pero es que el filtro del color o mejor dicho su url no tendría porqué coger más parámetros. La url no se mete en los filtros, a no ser que tengas un tipo de filtro especial. Me refiero a que puedes estar en la pagina 1000 pero si quieres ver color es una url diferente a no ser que estés filtrando con marca y ahí si el color se agrega a los parámetros shop/?filter_brand=phoenix&filter_color=black pero si no es con marca no deberías tener problemas

Si entiendo, el problema es que el filtro se aplica sobre la misma url, por lo que incluye el 1/page/3 y al no haber pagina 3 con los resultados del filtrado, por eso dice que no ha encontrado la pagina

ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/621197/81450
